# Why are my questions not getting views?

Tags: discussion

Why are my questions not getting views? Even if they get some views, there aren't any answers or votes.

Comment: Can you give an example? I did not look on your questions so far, but in my experience many users have problems with choosing the correct tags and title, to start with. Also, questions with poor MathJax skills are not interacted with a lot (again, my personal experience).

Comment: Maybe users of this site aren’t that keen on fluid dynamics, which is a topic very big in engineering or applied math?

Answer (score 4):

> Why my questions are not getting views?

One possibility is that your questions are poorly written and/or not appropriate for this forum. Did you review the [Help section](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on this topic?

---

Further, I took a look at [a recent question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/793877/why-equilibrium-and-not-steady-state) of yours and it is not the kind of question that I would usually interact with or attempt to answer.

It seems like this recent question is about the semantics of the words "equilibrium" and "steady state." If that is not the case, it still seems that way to me. You have to write your questions in a way that your audience can understand what you mean. Maybe try re-writing the question with a focus on clarity of meaning.

Also, it seems like this recent question is based on your own (perhaps incorrect) perspective regarding what "we" do. Also, your recent question seem to misapply universal qualifiers: "Why **only** state of equilibrium is used..." (Emphasis added.) Why do you suppose "only" "state of equilibrium" is used? Have you surveyed all the literature to ensure that "only" "state of equilibrium" is used? Also, double checking your grammar and spelling before you post a question would probably help too. See, for example, [this Help page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

---

Also, you are (at least sometimes) asking [*homework-like* questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/801836/query-regarding-approach-to-solve-a-fluid-kinematics-problem).

It does not matter if the above-linked question is not **literally** a homework problem. It is homework-**like**. Again, there is a [help section](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and a [meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) about this topic.

Comment: [It is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Comment: It is not supposed to be a *discussion* forum, but it is arguably *a forum*. And, of course, many users seem to believe it is a discussion forum (despite the help section indicating it is not). But, what is your point?

Answer (score 2):

I see six undeleted questions, of which four have upvoted answers. That's not too shabby.

Your four deleted questions all seem to be self-deletions. The closed ones would have eventually been pruned by an automatic process, but the ones you deleted while they were open might have gotten more traction if you hadn't deleted them.

If you would like to feature your questions for additional attention, you can click "start a bounty" under the question. The bounty process is described in the Help Center.

If you would like some interactive feedback about whether your questions are clear enough to get good answers, you might ask politely in "the h bar," our chat room. There's a chat link near the bottom of this page.